# How do I add text in sequence in one text view when different buttons are clicked?

Tags: android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I am having a problem in Android Studio. I have got two different buttons and a textView. The effect that I want is as follows:

> CASE 1: When bt1 is clicked, "A" is displayed in textView. When the bt2 is clicked, "G" is added in textView so the textView displays "AG".
>
> CASE 2: When bt1 is clicked, "A" is displayed in textView. When bt1 is clicked again, it disappears and the textView is empty.
>
> CASE 3: When CASE 1 is done, as bt1 is clicked, "A" is removed so that textView displays"G".

Your help in altering my code is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Main Activity code:

```
public class keyboard 
extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void 
onCreate(Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);
text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v){
        text.setText("A");
        text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override

    public void onClick(View v){
        text.setText(text.getText() + "G");
        text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
});}
```

Comment: You should try putting your each button value in an array and try reading it one by one.

Comment: But I am not so familiar with array ... Can you give some help me edit the code so that I can roughly know the concept.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to toggle `A` and `G` in your `TextView`:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String curText = text.getText().toString();
        if (curText.contains("A")) {
            text.setText(curText.replace("A", ""));
        } else {
            text.setText("A" + curText);
        }
    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        String curText = text.getText().toString();
        if (curText.contains("G")) {
            text.setText(curText.replace("G", ""));
        } else {
            text.setText(curText + "G");
        }
    }
});}
```

Comment: The above implementation works for only one Character. If the use is happy with toggling of only 1 character, Your approach is good enough

Comment: Yang Liu, is there any way to shorten my codes if I want to perform the same task that you showed me? Coz I have got many buttons to perform that same task...

Comment: In order of the letters doesn't matter, you can make the code inside `onClick()` into a function, like `updateText(String letter) {}`. Then pass the letters that you want into this function. `updateText("A")`, `updateText("G")`.

Comment: The order of letters matter for me.I doesn't mean to shorten the code that you shared with me, but to shorten button.setOnClickListener()...... something like that. This is because I have seen something like button.setOnClickListener(this)...... , so that this line of code doesn't need to be repeated when I am coding for another button, but I am not sure whether I can shorten it or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
public class keyboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    TextView text;

    boolean isBtn1Clicked,isBtn2Clicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);
         text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
         btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);
         isBtn1Clicked = false;
         isBtn2Clicked = false;

         btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               if(!isBtn1Clicked){
                   text.setText("A");
               } else{
                   //remove 'A' from your TextView
               }

               //check your TextView
               if(text.getText().isEmpty()){
                   text.setVisibility.(View.INVISIBLE);
               }else {
                   text.setVisibility.(View.VISIBLE);
               }
           }});

         btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v){
               //same as btn1
         }});
}
```

I prefer doing this: use 2 TextViews and each button handle 1 TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I will mention the logic here, It's up to you to build it and improvise it further

- Declare an arraylist

> ArrayList btn1list = new ArrayList();
>
> ArrayList btn2list = new ArrayList();

- btn1.setOnClickListener add your text to list btn1mylist.add(mystring) only if your list is empty (!btn1list.size())
- btn2.setOnClickListener add your text to list btn2mylist.add(mystring) only if your list is empty (!btn2list.size())
- Set the text view reading the array values

**Sample Code:**

```
    public class keyboard 
    extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn1,btn2,btn3;
    TextView text;
    ArrayList<String> btn1list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> btn2list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void 
    onCreate(Bundle 
    savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyboard);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v){
          //  text.setText("A");
          //Check for the btn1List size if it is not empty add the value and show the text
    if(!bnt1List.size()){
       // get the array list of items and set text 
}
            text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v){
        //    text.setText(text.getText() + "G");
  //Check for the btn2List size if it is not empty add the value and show the text
    if(!bnt2List.size()){
       // get the array list of items and set text 
}
            text.setVisibility(text.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });}
```